# How to change from MM-YY to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a table in which the date is stored in column Q in the format MM-YY (the dash is the seperator in this case), and I need it to change to a MM/DD/YYYY format (using the / instead, with the DD defaulting to 01). Basically I need it to change from 01-20 (January 2020) to 01/01/2020, and to do this for every month going forward, as the date changes by month. Is this possible using VBA, or am I missing a built in feature?

Thanks

Comment: Have You tried to use `Format()` ?

Comment: Are your `MM-YY` formatted values actual date values or text looking like dates? I mean, if you re-format real date values, there is a day that belongs to that specific date. Defaulting to `01` will need some more work than just `Format()`, and yes, you can do this with build-in features (functions)

Comment: could be easier to do via Excel Formula - =TEXT(A1,"MM/DD/YYYY")

Comment: Both `Format()` using VBA and `TEXT()` using build-in functions do result in a string value which is not a true date value. So it's also important to know what your current data type is (date or string) AND what type you expect to get returned.

Comment: Depending on the data itself (string or actual date) you may need to run `.TextToColumns` to get to  a standard format, which would precede using `Format()`, `Range().Numberformat =`, or even the formula `=text()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. In cell R2, add the formula,

```
=TEXT(Q2,"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: It's a bit premature to answer this question without more details about the data OP is working with. Formatting a value with `TEXT` which you don't know what the `dd` part would be does not necessarily end up being the first day of a month. In other words, a datevalue being 15th of january 2019 formatted like `01-19` will return `01/15/2019`, with the possible disadvantage of being a string data too.